# String to hash in Ruby without JSON.parse

Tags: ruby

Just for the sake of understanding. I know JSON.parse could do this pretty easily, but without using that, how could this be made cleaner or more efficient?

```
string = "ounces: 10; contains_toy: false"
result = string.split("; ")
result = result.map{|x| x = x.split(": "); Hash[x.first.to_sym, x.last] }
result = result.reduce(:merge)
```

Desired result:

```
{:ounces=>"10", :contains_toy=>"false"}
```

Comment: Also for the sake of understanding: How would `JSON.parse` help? The string isn't close to being JSON. Keys would have to be quoted, commas instead of semicolons, braces around everything.

Comment: I was thinking something like this : `result = JSON.parse "{#{string.gsub(/([a-z_]+):/, '"\1":')}}"` was a little cleaner

Comment: With gsub + parse you'd probably hit the same issue that any sort of naïve string manipulation (including the code in my answer) has: Delimiter-tokens being taken taken out of context, and breaking things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Chain your calls. Don't update the same variable again and again with very different values.
2. Just construct a hash straight away with `each_with_object` or construct an array of pairs, and turn that into a hash.
3. Any sort of splitting/scanning is prone to errors if the string contains tokens that *aren't* part of the syntax. I.e. a nested string with a semicolon in it will be split as though it's a delimiter.

Anyway, you can do this, for instance:

```
result = Hash[ string.scan(/(\w+):\s+([^;]+)/) ]
```

though that'll give you string keys.

To avoid that, you could do:

```
pairs = string.scan(/(\w+):\s+([^;]+)/).map { |k,v| [k.to_sym, v.strip] }
result = Hash[pairs]
```

or

```
result = string.scan(/(\w+):\s+([^;]+)/).each_with_object({}) do |(k,v), hash|
  hash[k.to_sym] = v.strip
end
```

Another, much less robust way would be:

```
pairs = string.split(/[:;]/)
  .map(&:strip)
  .each_slice(2)
  .map { |k,v| [k.strip.to_sym, v.strip] }
result = Hash[pairs]
```

Edit: And the totally *unsafe* option would be

```
result = eval("{#{string.tr(';', ',')}}")
```

On the plus side, your values have proper types (not all strings). On the minus side, eval is evil, and should always be avoided. So, really, don't do this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation as well as the variations! Great explanation :)

Comment: @newUserNameHere Thanks - added another (really poor) alternative. But it's the shortest one yet.